# How do I target a "this" that is outside of its respective function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

Sorry if that title is confusing. Basically, I had to rewrite my code to implement the history api. Below is the before and after. You can see how *before*, the `this` keywords worked fine relative to `.post-link`. However, in the *after*, the `this` keywords don't work anymore since there is no relative point. How do I make sure that the correct links are targeted in the *after* function all relative to `.post-link` which is now a separate function?

**Before: Everything worked fine with `this` in relation to `.post-link`.**

```
$('#content').on('click', '.post-link', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var post_id = $(this).data('id'),
        projectTitle = $(this).data('title'),
        projectSlug = $(this).data('slug'),
        ajaxURL = site.ajaxurl;

    $('<span class="loading-icon"></span>').insertBefore(this);
    $(this).closest('article.project').addClass('active');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxURL,
        context: this,
        data: {'action': 'load-content', post_id: post_id },
        success: function(response) {
            $('.loading-icon').remove();
            $(this).closest('article.project').removeClass('active');
            $('#project-container').html(response);

            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

**After: Now the relative link (`.post-link`) is gone, so all the `this` keywords aren't functioning properly (marked as comments below).**

```
(function($) {
    function openProject() {
        var post_id = $(this).data('id'),                                 // this
            ajaxURL = site.ajaxurl;

        $('<span class="loading-icon"></span>').insertBefore(this);       // this
        $(this).closest('article.project').addClass('active');            // this

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxURL,
            context: this,                                                // added this
            data: {'action': 'load-content', post_id: post_id },
            success: function(response) {
                $('.loading-icon').remove();
                $(this).closest('article.project').removeClass('active'); // this

                $('#project-container').html(response)

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    // User event
    $('#content').on('click', '.post-link', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Variables
        var projectTitle = $(this).data('title'),
            projectSlug = $(this).data('slug');

        var newData = { project_page: site.url + '/projects/' + projectSlug };
        History.pushState(newData, projectTitle + ' | Site Title', site.url + '/projects/' + projectSlug);
        openProject();
    });

    // History event
    History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function(){
        var State = History.getState();
        $('#content').load(State.data.project_page);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: In your second conditional you didn't define `History`. You only do that in the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way here would be to call the function `openProject();` with `this` as parameter:

```
openProject(this);

function openProject(el){
    // do stuff with $(el);
}
```

However the more advanced way is to bind the function to the `this`-context or call the function in a specific context:

```
// binds the function to the object given.
// Whenever you call the function now `this` will refer to the given object
openProject.bind(this); 
openProject.apply(this);  // Calls the function in the context of the given Object
openProject.call(this);  // same here
```

Now the openProject-function is called in the context of the given `this` in your case that what you wanted.
You can improve that with binding `$(this)` instead to avoid calling jquery all the time you use `this`

**Edit:**
I missed the `this` in the ajax-callback. This `this` is not the same as in the openProject-function becaue the callback is called in another context.
In openProject you would do this:

```
var _this = this;

$.ajax({
    // Parameter and stuff
    success: function(){ 
        // use _this here 
    }
})
```

You should read about the use of `this` and how to handle it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: Where/how would I exactly implement `openProject.bind(this)();`? So far, I've changed the parameter for the function to `function openProject(el) {` and I'm calling it like this `openProject(this);`.

Comment: Normally you bind a function to a context right after you defined it. But you can do it anywhere. In your example you bind it right before you call it. Bind is better used for binding a function to a non-changing this. Use apply or call - that fits better here!

Comment: In your case: replace the function call openProject()  with openProject.call(this)

Comment: @J82 calling the function with `this` as parameter and *binding* `this` are 2 completely different approaches. If you pass `this` as parameter you have to change every use of `this` in the openProject-function to `el` because `el` is the `this` you passed. So just decide for one posibility. When you **only** change `openProject()` to `openProject.call(this)` your code will work as it is without any further changes needed

Comment: Ok, I tried only replacing `openProject()` to `openProject.call(this)` (and leaving everything else the same as above) and I can see that it's working, but it looks like jQuery is still being called. Is this normal?

Comment: I missed out the `this` in the ajax-callback. define a `var _this = this;` in your `openProject`-function and use it in the ajax-callback. You can see it partially working here: http://jsfiddle.net/g5svqj0t/ (i cant simulate the ajax-request but the other stuff (especially the `call`) is working)

Comment: I noticed that and used [.ajax context](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) as seen in the edited post above. Is that the same thing? If so, jQuery is still loading on my end.

Comment: `openProject.apply(this);` and `openProject.call(this);` do **not** bind `this` to the function `openProject`. `call` and `apply` can be use to call the function `openProject` in context of the object you passed, but it must be still be know at the time you use `call` or `apply`

Comment: of course that is true. I added call and apply later and didnt change the text. Will correct it. @J82 yes that will make it. Of course jQuery is loading since you are using it.

Comment: For the `ajax` the `var _this=this` should not be required, as the OP already uses `context: this` as option for the ajax call.

Comment: @Fuzzyma Sorry, meant to say that jQuery is being called each time, but actually I was wrong. It's not being called each time. Thank you for your help. :)